# Mean of any 5 numbers is 30, find the sum of all numbers

Tags: combinatorics

> There are 6 numbers. The mean of any 5 of the numbers must be 30. Find the sum of the 6 numbers.

The sum of any 5 numbers must be 150. There are 6 possibles cases, so the sum of the 6 numbers must be $150 \times 6 \div 5 = 180$.

But then I try to change the question:

> There are 6 numbers. The mean of any **$4$** of the numbers must be 30. Find the sum of the 6 numbers.

And I find that the sum is still $180$. I don't think that it is a coincident but I can't really tell what's the pattern behind this. Can anyone give me any hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since the mean of all numbers  taken $5$ at a time is $30 ,$ it is not hard to deduce that all numbers are equal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the mean of all numbers taken $5$ at a time is $30$, it is not hard to deduce that all numbers are equal , as it is not possible otherwise.

Or more generally if you have $x$ numbers and the mean of any numbers taken $2$ at a time is $y$ , then we can say that all the numbers are equal to each other.

For Proof , consider any two number $a$ and $b$. Let their sum be $S.$ Now let us consider a pair $a,c$.Since they have the same mean as $a,b$  their sum should be equal.Hence $a+b = a+c \implies b=c$.Using similar arguments , you can show that all numbers are equal to each other

Now in your case $5x = 150 \implies x= 30$

Hence no matter how many numbers you take at a time , the sum is always $6 \times 30 =180.$

Comment: Note: only if $x > 2$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your proof can be easily generalized to my case!

Answer (score 0):

Let a, b, c, d, e, f be the 6 numbers. Because the mean of any 4 is 30, the sum of any 4 is 120. So

a+b+c+d=120

b+c+d+e=120

c+d+e+f=120

d+e+f+a=120

e+f+a+b=120

f+a+b+c=120

Adding all these equations together gives 4(a+b+c+d+e+f)=6.120, and so a+b+c+d+e+f=180.

Comment: I know how to solve this question. I am wondering why the two cases will both have the sum as 180.

Comment: Basically, because the average of a set of appropriately chosen averages is just the same as an average.